# Are MergedDictionaries parsed every time?

Tags: wpf, performance, xaml

Consider a WPF `UserControl` which defines the following resources:

```
<UserControl.Resources >
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="LeftHeaderDataTemplates.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="RightHeaderDataTemplates.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Will the merged resources be parsed for every instance of the user control? The Application Time Line in the Performance Profiler appears to indicate so, but I'm not sure, if I'm reading the results correctly.

**EDIT**

As @Andy's answer pointed out: yes, the ResourceDictionary is parsed each time and a new instance is created. In the comments below he mentioned that there was a "better way" for referencing Converters, namely letting them implement `MarkupExtension` as shown in the link he provided.

This raised the question, how many converter instances are created, depending on which way they are referenced/implemented. I thought I'd add my findings here, because I found it relevant in the context of my initial question.

Consider a UserControl that is rendered 4 times:

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <converters1:TestConverter3 x:Key="TestConverter3"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <StackPanel Background="Black">
        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TestConverter1}}"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TestConverter1}}"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Converter={converters1:TestConverter2}}"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Converter={converters1:TestConverter2}}"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TestConverter3}}"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TestConverter3}}"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

In addition, `TestConverter1` is defined as a global/shared/static resource in **App.xaml** and `TestConverter2` is implemented by inheriting **`MarkupExtension`**.

All in all there are 3 different converters, each used twice by 4 instances of the UserControl.

This created the following console output (with added blank lines):

```
CREATING: TestConverter1 {HashCode: 51949120}
                                             
CREATING: TestConverter2 {HashCode: 27832883}
CREATING: TestConverter2 {HashCode:  8329199}
CREATING: TestConverter3 {HashCode: 48129282}
                                             
CREATING: TestConverter2 {HashCode: 12052844}
CREATING: TestConverter2 {HashCode: 24470370}
CREATING: TestConverter3 {HashCode: 24336447}
                                             
CREATING: TestConverter2 {HashCode: 22270914}
CREATING: TestConverter2 {HashCode: 23473221}
CREATING: TestConverter3 {HashCode: 11043085}
                                             
CREATING: TestConverter2 {HashCode: 50932452}
CREATING: TestConverter2 {HashCode: 32788649}
CREATING: TestConverter3 {HashCode: 49189852}

Convert     : TestConverter1 {HashCode: 51949120}
Convert     : TestConverter1 {HashCode: 51949120}
Convert     : TestConverter2 {HashCode: 27832883}
Convert     : TestConverter2 {HashCode:  8329199}
Convert     : TestConverter3 {HashCode: 48129282}
Convert     : TestConverter3 {HashCode: 48129282}
                                                 
Convert     : TestConverter1 {HashCode: 51949120}
Convert     : TestConverter1 {HashCode: 51949120}
Convert     : TestConverter2 {HashCode: 12052844}
Convert     : TestConverter2 {HashCode: 24470370}
Convert     : TestConverter3 {HashCode: 24336447}
Convert     : TestConverter3 {HashCode: 24336447}
                                                 
Convert     : TestConverter1 {HashCode: 51949120}
Convert     : TestConverter1 {HashCode: 51949120}
Convert     : TestConverter2 {HashCode: 22270914}
Convert     : TestConverter2 {HashCode: 23473221}
Convert     : TestConverter3 {HashCode: 11043085}
Convert     : TestConverter3 {HashCode: 11043085}
                                                 
Convert     : TestConverter1 {HashCode: 51949120}
Convert     : TestConverter1 {HashCode: 51949120}
Convert     : TestConverter2 {HashCode: 50932452}
Convert     : TestConverter2 {HashCode: 32788649}
Convert     : TestConverter3 {HashCode: 49189852}
Convert     : TestConverter3 {HashCode: 49189852}
```

Results:

- TestConverter1, used/defined as a static resource in **App.xaml** is created 1 time.
- TestConverter2, used/defined as a **markup extension** is created 8 times (once for each use).
- TestConverter3, used/defined as a static resource within the **UserControl** is created 4 times (once per control).

Of course, Converters are to be light-weight so this will often not be an issue (regarding memory or garbage collection), but I nonetheless thought is was worth observing, especially, if you choose the indeed very slick MarkupExtension syntax.

Comment: Yes - it will.
And even more. If you set a DynamicResource, then this will work similar to a binding. When you change the resource, replace the dictionary, change the level of the resource - the value of DynamicResource will be re-evaluated.

Comment: @EldHasp: thanks! if you'd posted as an answer, i'd accepted that as _the one_ ;o)

Comment: Not just parsed each time. There's an instance in memory for each user control. So be careful about big resources if you will have a lot of instances.

Comment: @Andy: yes, i see now, this also applies to all resources, e.g. if the resource is a `Converter` a new instance will be created for every `UserControl`.

Comment: True. But there's a better way to do converters.

Comment: @Andy: you tease ;o) could you elaborate?

Comment: http://drwpf.com/blog/2009/03/17/tips-and-tricks-making-value-converters-more-accessible-in-markup/

Comment: @Andy: I looked into the MarkupExtension approach, and I haven't had time to isolate and test the issue, but first glance debuggin appears to show that regarding instantiation/garbage a new instance is created every time the converter is referenced, which is even more times than in the markup of my post (where a new instance is created for each definition).

Comment: Static means singleton.

Comment: @Andy: Yes, of course, static=singleton, but the `ProvideValue` method is an instance method, the must be called on an actual instance (presumably created by WPF using reflection) that then returns a shared/static/singleton instance - instead of just itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - it will.
And even more. If you set a DynamicResource, then this will work similar to a binding. When you change the resource, replace the dictionary, change the level of the resource - the value of DynamicResource will be re-evaluated.